# How to extract substrings that start and end with a specific character, in a single string?

Tags: r, string, substring

For example I have the following string:

```
sample = "I am a good guy; he is cool; I am a cool dude; let's do it!"
```

I need to find substrings which start with "I am" and end with ";" so the output should be like:

```
I am a good guy
I am a cool dude
```

Any suggestions how to do this in R? Thanks

Comment: You need that in R programming riight ?

Comment: @rUCHit31yes . sorry for the confusion. I will edit the question and make this clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a stringr library solution:

```
str_match_all(sample, "I am.*?;")
#[[1]]
#     [,1]               
#[1,] "I am a good guy;" 
#[2,] "I am a cool dude;"
```

stringer has several very powerful functions for dealing with splitting and extracting information from strings.

Answer (score 4):

You can use regular expressions. For example

```
regmatches(sample, gregexpr("I am [^;]+;", sample))
# [[1]]
# [1] "I am a good guy;"  "I am a cool dude;"
```

Note that since we can have multiple matches per string, R returns a list of vectors. Just be aware when you go to work with the results.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `str_extract_all`

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(sample, "I am [^;]+(?=;)")[[1]]
#[1] "I am a good guy"  "I am a cool dude"
```